# Toggling div-size via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to use `javascript` to toggle the size of a `div`. In order to understand the basic idea of how to do this I tried replicating this example: [Toggling Div (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/)

But for some reason it is not working, despite me having copied it from the working JSFiddle. Why is that? Here is my replicate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <style type="text/css">#topbar {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    height: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    }</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#topbar").click((function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        $(this).animate({
            height: (++i % 2) ? 40 : 10
        }, 200);
    }
    })());

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id='topbar'>toggle me</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wow!** You haven't added jQuery at all! Add this in your `<head>` before you call the script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You must have got this error in the console:

```
Reference Error: $ not defined.
```

---

You are using `this` not in context. When you put it inside a function, then it gets screwed up. Do it this way:

```
$(function () {
    $("#topbar").click(function () {
        var i = 0;
        $(this).animate({
            height: (++i % 2) ? 40 : 10
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
});
```

The `this` you used, will be taking your inner function as its context. And since your `<div>` comes after the `<script>`, please enclose it inside the `$(function () {})`.

Comment: Sorry that was a shame.

Comment: @FurkanO Sorry for being rude, dude. Really sorry.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Now, a follow-up question: The current script toggles the width of the div using absolute pixel values. How can I use percentage-values instead?

Comment: @JoSch You can just replace the size in `px` with `%` and it should work.